# Authorizing <app-route> paths using <firebase-auth> in Polymer 1.0

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, google-signin, firebase-authentication

Just getting started with Polymer 1.0. My Single Page Polymer 1.0 application has multiple routes.

```
    <paper-drawer-panel id="mainPanel" class="flex" >
       <app-router id="router" class="flex" mode="pushstate">
         <app-route path="/" element="page-landing"></app-route>
         <app-route path="/user" element="page-user"></app-route>
         <app-route path="/admin" element="page-admin"></app-route>
         ....// more <app-routes>
       </app-router>
    </paper-drawer-panel>
```

I would like to use `<firebase-auth>` with ***google as provider*** on landing page `<page-landing>`;

On Successful Authentication, I would like to navigate to ***`<app-route>` paths*** based on *authorization*

- `<page-admin>` only ***ADMIN*** can see
- `<page-user>` **any logged in user** can see

Say `<page-landing>` provides option to login as Admin or User.

How do I implement Authorization based routes? And in all `<app-routes>` I need to check the user isAuthorized or not. Could any one please point to an example of implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at iron-meta to store pagewide states like `isAuthorized`.

For distinguishing between secured pages and public once, you have to take care yourself. Use a change observer for the page path or selecteditem or similar.

Regarding authentication and authorization you are in bad luck, because all subpages are imported via the html link tag and you cannot attach any header.
But actually it is not really a problem. Because in general you like to secure the data of each page and not the whole itself. And html import only loads the view/page-template and you still have to populate it with the client data. This you usually request with an ajax call, which you can give an auth-header as normal.

Hope these descriptions help you find your way...

Comment: Thanks Kjell for your valuable inputs. I'll try `<iron-meta>` and update.